# Any app for Instagram on Ubuntu 22.04 using Wayland?

Tags: 22.04, instagram

I installed Instagraph using snap but it didn't display anything  & just died (i.e. not showing on System Monitor). Snap didn't find instagramport. ramme from github didn't display anything and died. Any other ideas for a working app for Instagram on Ubuntu 22.04 using Wayland?
PS using URL instagram.com doesn't allow a new posting of a captioned photo.